# another word for "tight schedule" and the quality to hand the tight schedule?

Tags: word-request

1.For the sentence" the schedule is tight", and is there any other words to express the same meaning with the adjective" tight" ?
2. i would like to say some one have the quality that are able to handle the tight schedule, how to express that kind of quality?
Thanks!

Comment: "The project schedule is tight" is a very good way to express this idea.  Why are you looking for something different?

Comment: Oh, i just want find another word, may be an adjective to say that?  is there any words appropriate?

Comment: Not exactly what you are after, but if someone is _on the **critical path,**_ any delay in his work will result in overall project delay.  Someone who is not on the critical path can finish her work today or tomorrow, and the overall project will still finish on time.  The second person has _float_ or _float time._  NOTE:  These are technical terms used in project management.  To the lay person, the most common term **by far** is that the schedule is tight.

Comment: Thank you, it's pretty clear now, and only one little question, what is "lay person"?

Comment: A "lay person" (or "layman", "layperson") in this context is a non-expert. Originally the adjective "lay" (and the noun "laity") designated ordinary Christians, those not in religious orders; but for the past century or so "lay" has been extended to ordinary people without advanced technical understanding of whatever field is under discussion.

Answer (score 2):

When a project schedule is **tight**, there is usually less time to complete the project than person or team assigned to it really needs for it. That means that they will have to stay focused on the task at all times, or sometimes work faster than they normally would, or work extra hours during the week, depending on how "tight" the schedule is (and on the country where the job is located, since there are a few countries which do not permit exploitation of workers).

Typical phrases used to describe a candidate for such a job involving tight schedules:

... must be task-oriented

... must stay focused

... must be able to handle pressure

... must respect deadlines

... must be willing to stay late

... must be willing to work weekends*

<sup>* where permissible</sup>

If you had to sum those things up in a single *quality*, the most commonly used word in job descriptions (in AmE) is **dedicated**.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [juggle](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/juggle):

> 1. *verb*
>      If you juggle lots of different things, for example your work and your family, you try to give enough time or attention to all of them.
>      *The management team meets several times a week to **juggle** budgets and resources.
>
>      Mike **juggled** the demands of a family of 11 with a career as a TV reporter.*

You wouldn't call that person a *juggler* though (the usual meaning is different). Maybe a person who can juggle various activities to follow a tight schedule.

Other words to describe such a person might be *multitasking* or *versatile*.

Answer (score 0):

> She is someone with **good time-management skills**
>
> She is good at **working under pressure**.
>
> She is **able to meet (her) deadlines**.

more informal

> She is a **[go-to player](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/go-to-guy)**.
>
> She is a **performer**.
>
> She is a **crunch-time player**.